# How to get all web form elements value

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have a simple web form which consists of several text box and drop downs. I need a way to get the value of all of the elements from the start in a list. I know I can individually get the value using textbox1.value but I wouldn't know how many textbox/dropdown there are in the form. 
For example

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Tier: 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Tier" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select Tier</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Tier1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Tire2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Tier3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        Author: 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Author" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select Author</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Author1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Author2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Author3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        Quotation For:
            <asp:TextBox ID="questionfor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

How do I get the value in a list ? How do I loop through them ? The final aim is to store the element Id and its value in the database. Hence along with the value I need the id as well. For example in the database I will have two column elementName(which is the elementID) and its corresponding value.

Comment: you can do this several ways.. if you understand `Lambda's` and how to do a foreach you can do this based on the Controls type.. or you could do it the old fashion way and use a `foreach(Control ctrl in Controls)` checking if typs is `DropDowList` or TextBox..etc.. pretty simple actually

Answer (score 0):

here is something you can try

```
Protected void GetControlValues(ControlCollection  controls)
{
    var holdList = new List<string>();
    foreach(Control c in controls)
    {
        if(c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
        {
            holdList.Add(c.Text); //this will get the value of the TextBox 
        } 
        else if (c.controls.Count > 0)
        {
            GetControlValues(c.Controls)
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to get the ID value then you could check `if(c.ID == textBoxId.ID)` then add that textBoxId.Text to the List you can have multiple if checks inside this foreach loop if you know the types of controls you are checking..

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: BTW: _No_ control is of type `ListItem`.

Comment: I will edit the answer to show recursion using a foreach(Controls loop

Comment: why just dropdownlist? Will this also take  care of textbox? or for that matter any other elements like checkbox, etc ?

Comment: you need you can do this for every control if you check the types using a `foreach(Control ctrl in Controls)` you need to check check using `if(c is TextBox)` for example.. it's pretty straight forward ..I will do edit and show you how using a `TextBox` then it will make more sense

Comment: there seems to be something wrong with controls. It shows count as 5 when i have more than 5 elements. And they are represented at  {System.Web.UI.LiteralControl}

Comment: then you need to change the code to check if it's `System.Web.UI.LiteralControl`